# Number of fractional transformations between same three points

Tags: complex-analysis

I am unsure of how many fractional transformations there are between a given triple of points and the same triple of points, if the points can be in any order ? ovbiously w = z is one butI think there are 9 possibilities. Are there any that are duplicates or equivalent.

Can any one expand on this ?

Answer (score 0):

A "linear fractional transformation" or "Möbius transformation" is uniquely
determined by the values at three pairwise different points $z_1, z_2, z_3 $.

If you are looking for linear fractional transformation mapping 
$\{ z_1, z_2, z_3 \} $ to itself (in any order), then there are exactly 6 of them: one for each permutation of $(z_1, z_2, z_3)$.

Comment: Thank you Martin. However, I must admit, I still get 9 ...can't see the wood for the trees ! let me explain my thinking. For each variation of the starting triple there are 3 possibilities; to the same point and the other two variants. This gives 9. Where am I missing the/your point.

Comment: @Callie12: You have 3 choices for the first point, then 2 choices for the second and one point for the third. Explicitly: (a, b, c) can be mapped to (a, b, c), (a, c, b), (b, a, c), (b, c, a), (c, a, b) or (c, b, a). That are 6 possibilities, corresponding to the 6 permutations of three elements.

Comment: Got you ! Sorry for being so slow. Appreciate your response Martin

Comment: @Callie12: You are welcome! (You might consider to *accept* the answer if it helped :)